# Tagging: Would Serif and Sans-Serif tags be worthwhile?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just asked a question about fonts, where I was specifically asking about sans-serif fonts.

It occurred to me that there may be a tag for that, but I found that there wasn't. I think that as the site continues to grow and more font questions get asked, it may be a good idea to have a few ways to filter the font questions categorically.

Would it be a good idea to create [serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serif) and [sans-serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif) tags?

It would be better to deal with the kerfuffle of adding tags at this stage, than two years from now when it's an overwhelming task.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a good idea. Used intelligently, of course. I think a lot of the tags used are not diverse enough, serif and sans-serif makes complete sense to me (i would also vote for a tag "bitmap". It would be a good idea to do some general tag-cleaning and tag diversity).

Answer (score 4):

**I like it as well.** They are widely known, and they would be a good way of locating similar questions (and they are not software related! yay!). I think it goes perfectly with the aim of focusing on graphic design by having *thematic areas* (typography *theory*, for example).

Something that came to mind, though, just as a (silly) consideration: If we welcome serif and sans-serif, does it mean we will eventually include other type tags such as script or decorative?

Comment: I suppose it does open the door to other font categories, but I think it'll take a long time before there are enough questions in those categories. Does serif and sans serif cover all fonts broadly or do slab, script and decorative etc stand alone?

Comment: I see no reason why we could not have slab, decorative, handwriting etc too. It would be quite specific to the post in question given that there are only five tags allowed. If the tag is descriptive and specific, so much the better.

Answer (score 2):

With tags..... you just add them to your question. They then go into the pool of tags, so if someone else starts to type "san..." or "seri...." they get the tag pop up. If the tag is used it stays. If no one ever uses it again it'll go away.

There's nothing specific which needs to be done to add tags, if you have the rep, just ask a question and use the tags you think should be added.

.... at least that's how I understand things. I have been known to be wrong though.

Comment: I know *how* I just don't know if there's any point. As you've said, if no-one ever uses it again it'll go away. Raising it as a topic here could at least raise awareness enough to give it some traction, *if* people think it's a good idea. Additionally, I'll look at past questions and add these tags if the community response is generally agreeable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how often we'd need to put these into separate meta-data buckets. I can see maybe some more refined type classification buckets, but just two giant sans vs. serif doesn't seem all that useful to me.

Comment: So are you open to other font classification tags such as slab, script, blackletter etc? I'm starting to think that if we add these we might as well try to add them all. I'm considering posting a question asking about the different characteristics of each font category, which I can also use to create the new tags. It may take two questions to cover all categories. Do you (and anyone bothering to read this) think that they would be appropriate questions for the main site?

Comment: It seems to me to be an all or nothing proposition. Either we should have a full range of type classification tags, or we shouldn't just stick with 'typography' by itself.