# Tagging: What should the Serif and Sans-Serif tags be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inevitably, the next question in series.

Previously: [Tagging: Would Serif and Sans-Serif tags be worthwhile?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/820/would-serif-and-sans-serif-tags-be-worthwhile)

The community response has been generally agreeable about creating these tags; now I'm wondering what they should and shouldn't be used for.

1. Should they be added to **all** [font-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) questions that involve a Serif or Sans Serif?

   - This may or may not be a good idea, the positives I see are that many questions that only have [font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font) and/or [font-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) will have one more categorical reference. The negatives; it may be that people are not looking for that when they click on the tag or search for the phrase.
2. Should they only be reserved for typographical questions that specifically mention either [serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serif) or [sans-serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif) as a topic of discussion?

It would be good if we could figure out what a user might expect to find when searching the site for these topics.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with the **second use** (tag for typographical questions).

I don't see a great value in adding the serif/sans-serif tag to existing font-identification questions. I don't imagine people generally looking for serif + font-id in a search, as there really would be no value (font-id questions, in general, are not really that much visited unless they refer to a known brand, movie or similar). And the process of adding the tags to the existing questions would take a long time, as we don't want to bump all of them to the top.

I do like the idea of the **tag as a descriptive discussion tag for typography.** We don't have that many typography questions yet, but we certainly want to :) I see you have edited some existing ones, it makes complete sense, they look great.

But I don't really see anything negative with adding the tags to *any* type of question, so I'd love to hear some more opinions!

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with adding those tags, but if we're going to add those, why not script, blackletter, and grotesque? I'm being serious — if the goal is to help us categorize font questions, then let's establish all the standard categories.

Start with the ones in the gorgeous [Periodic Table of Typefaces.](http://www.squidspot.com/Periodic_Table_of_Typefaces/Periodic_Table_of_Typefaces_large.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me.

Comment: The problem is I don't personally know of any questions that we could add those tags to. To create a tag you add it to a question as you prolly know *but* it also has to be added to at least one more question (*I think - could be more*) for it to stay in the tag pool permanently. If you know of some questions to tag with those, tag away! :)